# How to calculate approximate changes in a nonlinear function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

first off I've not really studied math so I'm kind of in deep water.

Lets assume that $f(a,b)=y=1+a/b$ and that both variables can increase and decrease in a given scenario.

Then lets assume that the above function is used to calculate $y$ in two different time periods; $0,1$ then we can do the following:

$$y_0=1+a_0/b_0$$
$$y_1=1+a_1/b_1$$

and thereby calculate the delta function as $Δy=y_1-y_0$ or
$$Δy=(1+a_1/b_1)-(1+a_0/b_0)$$

My question is then the following, how do i compute the approximate change in the value of $Δy$ due to a change in $Δa$ and $Δb$

Comment: If $\Delta a$ and $\Delta b$ are small, then you can use linear approximation; this is the main subject of differential calculus. If $f$ is nice then you may be able to use higher degree polynomial approximation even if $\Delta a$ and/or $\Delta b$ is not small. Otherwise you're just stuck with what you have.

Comment: $Δa$ and $Δb$ can both be small or big and also negative. when you say "Otherwise you're just stuck with what you have" does that mean i might not be able to calculate the approximate changes dependent of the size? Also as alternative i could live with only having the proportion of $a$ and $b$ in year 1 $y1=1+a1/b1$, but can this be calculated as simple as $a/(a+b)$ and $b/(a+b)$ when the variables are correlated?

Comment: For a totally general nonlinear function, no. For this one specifically you can do some simple algebra: $\frac{a_1}{b_1} - \frac{a_0}{b_0} = \frac{a_1 b_0 - a_0 b_1}{b_0 b_1} = \frac{a_1 b_0 - a_1 b_1 + a_1 b_1 - a_0 b_1}{b_0 b_1} = \frac{a_1}{b_0 b_1}(b_0 - b_1) + \frac{1}{b_0}(a_1-a_0)$. So this writes the difference in the ratios in terms of the difference of the numerators and the difference of the denominators.

Comment: Also as alternative i could live with only having the proportion of $a$ and $b$ in year 1 $y_1=1+a_1/b_1$, but can this be calculated as simple as $a/(a+b)$ and $b/(a+b)$ when the variables are correlated?

Comment: @Ian in your algebra above, could you give me an example of how it would be used to calculate the differences. e.g. $$a_0=5,b_0=15,a_1=7,b_1=22$$

Comment: Sure, you get $\frac{7}{15 \cdot 22}(15-22)+\frac{1}{15}(7-5)=\frac{-49}{330}+\frac{2}{15}=\frac{-5}{330}=\frac{-1}{66}$.

Comment: @Ian thank you, and how would you interpret the result? would you say that $-1/65$ comes from $Δa$ and $66/65$ comes from $Δb$

Comment: $-49/330$ comes from $\Delta b$ and $44/330$ comes from $\Delta a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the variation of $y$ vs. $(a,b)$ as:

$$\Delta y=|\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial a}|\Delta a+|\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial b}|\Delta b $$ so you have:

$$\Delta y=|\dfrac{1}{b}|\Delta a+|\dfrac{a}{b^2}|\Delta b$$

Comment: You shouldn't have absolute values.

Comment: Thank you for the help. as i said in the beginning my math is quite limited so i think i need to see this with an example to be able understand it. e.g. $$a_0=5  , b_0=15  ,  a_1=7  , b_1=22$$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra would you be able to explain how this would work in terms of finding $Δa$ proportion of $Δy$?

Comment: @SebastianKoefoed: if you keep $b$ constant and you know $\Delta a$ you can find the variation of $\Delta y$ vs. $\Delta a$. Same for $\Delta b$. Simply, the value of $\Delta y$ is depending on the values of $a$ and $b$, so you have: $\Delta y=f(a,b,\Delta a,\Delta b)$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra Okay, i think i more or less understand it. a few questions though, if i hold $b$constant, then $Δb=0$ correct? Also, in your formula in the original comment, how do i distinguish between time $t=0,t=1$. and last question, is the formula in the original comment Total derivative?

Comment: This is really more about uncertainty than actual error.

Comment: @SebastianKoefoed: if you keep $a$ and $b$ constant, for example $a=a_0$, $b=b_0$ this doesn't mean the error $\Delta a$ and $\Delta b$ in that point is zero. Yes it is the total derivative